# BigQuery accessing CustomDimensions with new SQL syntax

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am migrating to the new SQL syntax in BigQuery, since it seems more flexible. However I am a bit stuck when it comes to access the fields in the customDimensions. I am writing something quite simple like this:

```
SELECT 
  cd.customDimensions.index,
  cd.customDimensions.value
FROM `xxxxx.ga_sessions_20170312`, unnest(hits) cd
limit 100
```

But I get the error

```
Error: Cannot access field index on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>
```

However if I run something like this works perfectly fine:

```
    SELECT 
        date,
        SUM((SELECT SUM(latencyTracking.pageLoadTime) FROM UNNEST(hits))) pageLoadTime,
        SUM((SELECT SUM(latencyTracking.serverResponseTime) FROM UNNEST(hits))) serverResponseTime
   FROM `xxxxxx.ga_sessions_20170312`
    group by 1
```

Is there some different logic when it comes to query the customDimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the intention is to retrieve all custom dimensions in a flattened form, then join with `UNNEST(customDimensions)` as well:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  cd.index,
  cd.value
FROM `xxxxx.ga_sessions_20170312`,
  unnest(hits) hit,
  unnest(hit.customDimensions) cd
limit 100;
```

Comment: oh, it needs to cross join with both tables. Ok I get it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
fullvisitorid,
( SELECT MAX(IF(index=1,value, NULL))FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS CustomDimension1,
( SELECT MAX(IF(index=2,value, NULL))FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS CustomDimension2
FROM
  `XXXXXXX`, unnest(hits) as hits
```